# Check if Apache is Installed in Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, aws, amazon

How can I check if Apache is installed in my Amazon Linux AMI, which is based on RHEL 6? In Ubuntu, I use:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep apache
```

But that doesn't work in this case. Note, I need to be able to tell if Apache is installed even if it isn't a service.

Comment: Maybe you could try using the `locate` command? If the locate service is properly set up, try doing a `locate apache`. Another option is to use `find`, such as: `find /usr -name 'apache*'`.

Comment: If Linux AMI is Red Had based distro, then it uses rpm packages (not deb). The tool to manage rpm package is not `dpkg` but `rpm`. You may find if apache was installed using package by issuing a command like: `rpm -qa | grep -i apache`

Answer (score 6):

Two options that spring to my mind:

```
yum info httpd
```

check the output to see if it is installed or not, you get something like:

```
[0 1003 12:18:33] ~ % yum info httpd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de
 * extras: ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de
 * remi: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * remi-php56: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * remi-safe: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * updates: ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de
Installed Packages
Name        : httpd
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.2.15
Release     : 47.el6.centos
Size        : 2.9 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : updates
Summary     : Apache HTTP Server
URL         : http://httpd.apache.org/
License     : ASL 2.0
Description : The Apache HTTP Server is a powerful, efficient, and extensible
            : web server.
```

or do

```
rpm -qf /etc/httpd
```

to see if any package thinks it's responsible for httpd's config directory – on CentOS6, you get

```
[0 1001 12:12:46] ~ % rpm -qf /etc/httpd
httpd-2.2.15-47.el6.centos.x86_64
```

(and easiest last, convention on RH/CentOS is that the config lives in `/etc/httpd/`, so its mere presence might be a bit of an indicator.)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach is to invoke httpd, say by checking the version:

```
httpd -V
```